# Android Studio cannot find any connected device (tried with a few)

Tags: android, connection

I've tried connecting several devices for debugging but Android Studio cannot detect any of them, I've checked that the USB drivers are properly installed, and developer mode properly configured. I know its not a problem with my devices because I've tried them on other computers and they all work properly. Any ideas on what should I do?

Android Studio version: 2.1.2 running on a computer with Windows 8.1

Update: Reinstalling didn't work either

Update 2: After reinstalling all drivers I managed for Android Studio to detect most of my devices, excepting a Lenovo Yoga YT3-850 F tablet with Lollipop (Android 5.1), I tried updating the drivers and reinstalling them to no avail

Comment: What is the device that u are trying to get to work ? Did you try an emulator ?

Comment: tried restarting adb?

Comment: Type `adb version` to see what version it is, and then tell us. For example, my ADB version is 1.0.32.

Comment: Tried restarting it, emulator works fine, but still no device detected, adb version is 1.0.36

Comment: You might have to install device specific drivers for some devices (i.e Motorola, Samsung, HTC....). Check your manufacturer site to see if they have published such drivers.

Answer (score 2):

Close Android Studio, open terminal and run:
`killall adb`

Then open Android Studio, and run your project.
Hope I helped you.

Comment: Tried this, but no difference

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your connected device is compatible( min and max api)

Make sure that you have installed the proper driver by the following:

1. Open the `standalone Sdk manager` and check if **Google Usb Driver** is installed or not in the Extras section, if not install it.
2. Right Click on **My Computer** -> **Manage** -> **Device Manager**
3. Select your device and right click.
4. **Update Driver Software** -> **Browse my computer for driver software** -> **Let me pick from a list of device drivers from my computer** -> **Next** -> **Have Disk** -> **Browse**.
5. Now goto your google usb driver intalled location (its usually `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver`) and select **android_winusb.inf**

After that just follow some simple steps it shows.

Now it should work.

Comment: What simple steps?

Comment: Like clicking Open, Ok

Comment: Still no difference

Comment: If you have tried the steps exactly and it still doesnot work then the problem is something else. If you have enough RAM on your machine you should try the android studio emulator, its improved a lot from previous versions and its very fast.

Comment: I've been working on the emulator so far, but right now I need to run an app on a very specific device that still does not have an emulator version, will reinstall and post results.